# Getting array in JSON into a foreach using miniJSON

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am using the Facebook SDK in Unity to invite people to my game. When inviting I get a response with Facebook ID's of the persons I have invited. I would now like to actually create a game with them as opponent in my game and are able to do so if I could split the id's into a foreach loop, but I am not sure how to that.

Here is what the JSON response looks like:

```
{"to":["755111373","1144265875"],"request":"730979703615028"}
```

In Unity C# I then use MiniJSON (as preferred by Facebook) to get the data into an object like this:

```
var userReq = Json.Deserialize(fbresult.Text) as Dictionary<string,object>;
```

Now normally, if the object wasn't an array I would just get the data of each json object like this:

```
userReq["to"]
```

But, due to this being an array it is not possible. I have then tried to put it into a foreach loop like this:

```c#
foreach(var auser in userReq["to"]){
    int fbid = auser;
}
```

But this can not be done due to:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because it does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator' or is not accessible

I guess I have to put it into a list or dictionary first, but am not sure how I can do this. So how can I get the JSON values into a list I can iterate over?

Answer (score 2):

You should be simply able to cast the object to a `List<object>` and then iterate over that. 
For example, taking your data and doing the following:

```
var userReq = Json.Deserialize(fbresult.Text) as Dictionary<string,object>; 

List<object> numbers = (List<object>)(userReq["to"]);
foreach(string s in numbers)
{
    Debug.Log("Number: " + s);
}
```

Will print the two strings

> Number: 755111373
>   Number: 1144265875

in the console.